# Angular Springboot JWT : Not able to map the request

Tags: angular, spring-security, jwt, jjwt

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/senolatac/role-based-authorization) to learn the role based authentication

I am getting error of unauthorize

[image]

but in the backend I didnt get that request, added as breakpoint

```java
    @GetMapping("api/user/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(Principal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
        {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(principal);
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal;
        User user = userService.findByUsername(token.getName());
        user.setToken(jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(token));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
```

frontend request should come in the controller, but seems like I am getting response without entering in Controller.

Can anyone help with the possible reason.

configure method

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception
    {
        // Cross-origin-resource-sharing
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
            // These are public pages.
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/error", "/api/user/**").permitAll()
            // These can be reachable for just have admin role.
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            // all remaining paths should need authentication.
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
            // logout will log the user out by invalidate session.
            .logout().permitAll()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/user/logout", "POST")).and()
            // login form and path
            .formLogin().loginPage("/api/user/login").and()
            // enable basic authentication. Http header: basis username:password
            .httpBasic().and()
            // Cross side request forgery.
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { FormExampleComponent } from './form-example/form-example.component';
import { MaterialButtonsComponent } from './material-buttons/material-buttons.component';
import { MatButtonToggleComponent } from './mat-button-toggle/mat-button-toggle.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';
import { DisplaySectionComponent } from './display-section/display-section.component';
import { MaterialIconComponent } from './material-icon/material-icon.component';
import { MaterialBadgesComponent } from './material-badges/material-badges.component';
import { MatSpinnerComponent } from './mat-spinner/mat-spinner.component';
import { MaterialToolbarComponent } from './material-toolbar/material-toolbar.component';
import { MaterialSidenavComponent } from './material-sidenav/material-sidenav.component';
import { MaterialMenuComponent } from './material-menu/material-menu.component';
import { MaterialListComponent } from './material-list/material-list.component';
import { MaterialGridListComponent } from './material-grid-list/material-grid-list.component';
import { MaterialExpansionPanelComponent } from './material-expansion-panel/material-expansion-panel.component';
import { MaterialCardsComponent } from './material-cards/material-cards.component';
import { MaterialTabsComponent } from './material-tabs/material-tabs.component';
import { MaterialSteppersComponent } from './material-steppers/material-steppers.component';
import { MaterialInputComponent } from './material-input/material-input.component';
import { MaterialSelectComponent } from './material-select/material-select.component';
import { MaterialAutocompleteComponent } from './material-autocomplete/material-autocomplete.component';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';
import { OrderDetailsComponent } from './order-details/order-details.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail/detail.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { UnauthorisedComponent } from './unauthorised/unauthorised.component';
import {AuthGuard} from './guard/auth.guard';
import {Role} from './model/role';
import { SecurityComponent } from './security/security.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'security',component:SecurityComponent},
  {path:'main',component:MainComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'employees',component:EmployeeComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'profile',component:ProfileComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'detail/:id',component:DetailComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'admin',component:AdminComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path : 'display', component:DisplaySectionComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path: '', redirectTo:'signin',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path: 'formexample',component:FormExampleComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'matbutton',component:MaterialButtonsComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'matbuttontoggle',component:MatButtonToggleComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'signup',component:RegistrationComponent},
  {path:'signin',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'icon',component:MaterialIconComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'badge',component:MaterialBadgesComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'spinner',component:MatSpinnerComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'badge',component:MaterialBadgesComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'toolbar',component:MaterialToolbarComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'sidenav',component:MaterialSidenavComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'menu',component:MaterialMenuComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'list',component:MaterialListComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'gridlist',component:MaterialGridListComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'expansionlist',component:MaterialExpansionPanelComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'cards',component:MaterialCardsComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'tabs',component:MaterialTabsComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'stepper',component:MaterialSteppersComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'input',component:MaterialInputComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'select',component:MaterialSelectComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'autocomplete',component:MaterialAutocompleteComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'shopping',component:ShoppingCartComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path:'shopping/order',component:OrderDetailsComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{roles:[Role.ADMIN,Role.USER]}},
  {path : '404', component:PageNotFoundComponent},
  {path : '401', component:UnauthorisedComponent},
  {path : '**', component:PageNotFoundComponent}


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ enableTracing: true } )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
constructor(private router : Router){
this.router.errorHandler = (error:any)=>{
  this.router.navigate(['/404']);
}

}

}
```

on login click
    onLogin(user: any){
    console.log("this.user"+this.user);

```
this.userService.login(this.user).subscribe(data=>{
  console.log("data"+data);
  this.router.navigate(['/main']);
},err=>{
  this.errorMessage = "username or password is incorrect";
});
```

}

user service

```
login(user: User): Observable<any> {
console.log("user.username "+user.username );
const headers = new HttpHeaders(user ? {
  authorization: 'Basic '+btoa( user.username + ':' + user.password)
}:{});

return this.http.get<any> (API_URL + "login", {headers:headers}).pipe(
  map(response => {
    console.log("map"+response);
    if(response) {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response));
      this.currentUserSubject.next(response);
    }
    return response;
  })
);
```

}

Comment: Have a look at the spring securiy configuration of your app. It must currently prevent the user from reaching your login API. You should add something like ```.antMatchers("/api/user/login").permitAll()``` so that any user can reach it.

Comment: I have it, updated my question

Comment: Hey, any update on this, i really need to solve this

Comment: I have installed and run the app from the git repo : on the first run the ```user``` table is empty. Have you created a user account and checked the content of this table ?

Comment: Actually I have not copy pasted the exact code and for me almost all the things are same. I am updating my code for better reference.

Comment: I also installed it, and facing same issue of unauthorised

Comment: Did you check the content of the ```user``` table ?

Comment: Yes, first i created the user using the registration, then trying to use same user for authentication